# Mandalorian Armour Protection Level

Tags: star-wars, technology, the-clone-wars

How durable Is mandalorian/Death Watch armour and can it resist blaster bolts?

Answer (score 5):

Well, according to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_armor),

> "Numerous materials were employed in the creation of Mandalorian armor
>   through the millennia, from alum and durasteel, to
>   stygian-triprismatic polymer and the nearly indestructable beskar
>   iron."
>
> "Mandalorian armor was traditionally made out of almost indestructible
>   Mandalorian Iron (beskar), but this was rare and expensive, so many
>   Mandalorians, such as Jango and Boba Fett, opted for less durable
>   materials instead, such as durasteel or duraplast."

So it does depend on the material. However traditionally it is made from [beskar, or Mandalorian iron.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_iron)

> Armor forged of beskar could withstand blunt force, strikes from a
>   lightsaber, and repeated blasterfire, though the force of the impact
>   still transferred in part to the wearer.[9]

...

> Throughout Mandalorian history, three major features remained constant
>   in Mandalorian armor design:
>
> 1. The wearer was protected from the majority of all blaster fire. Armor made of actual Mandalorian iron, which could also deflect
>      blaster bolts, made it lightsaber-resistant.
> 2. The helmets almost always possessed a T-shaped visor and a sophisticated heads-up display (HUD).
> 3. Mandalorian warriors decorated their armor to reflect personal accomplishments, clan affiliation, or simply personal preference.

Comment: [Stygian](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Stygian_Iron)-triprismatic polymer - since when did they cross-over Star Wars and Percy Jackson? :)

Comment: Also, I would advise specifying the underlying canon references that Wikia is borrowing from.

Comment: Judging by the Qui-Gon Jinn scene with the blast door, lightsaber resistant armor would likely cook the person inside before a blade would "cut" through the armor. Yikes...